# How can I step into libc++ code on Mac OSX using lldb?

Tags: macos, lldb

I compiled my application with debug symbols using clang. When attaching to the application using lldb and stepping into, for example, __cxa_throw, I don't see the source code of libc++abi.dylib. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You do get some debug information for the STL, because a lot of the STL code is in header files that get compiled into your application.  But you don't have debug information for the code that is actually compiled into libc++abi.dylib, since Apple doesn't distribute dSYM's for system libraries.  __cxa_throw is actually a function in the library.

As a separate issue, because most people don't actually want to step into STL code, lldb has a setting:

```
(lldb) set show target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp
target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp (regex) = ^[^ ]+ std::|^std::
```

that will cause stepping to artificially step over code from the STL.  You can undo this by setting that value to "".  That will get you into the inlined code when stepping.

Comment: The command to undo that setting:

`set set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ""`